# Figure name in caption using RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, figure, caption

I am writing my first .rmd report using RMarkdown and then I knit it to pdf file. As I write it in my national language, I would like to have figures captions in my language too. The problem is that the default caption format is "Figure 1: My caption". I would like to change this generative "Figure 1:" part but I couldn't find how. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Try specifying the language in the YAML header of an `rmarkdown` document ([documentation link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex-options)):

```
---
title: "Crop Analysis Q3 2013"
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
lang: german
---
```

The language code will be processed by the [`babel` LaTeX package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en) (at least in the case of `pdflatex`).

Comment: I just needed to set `lang: de` as a "correct IETF language tag".

Answer (score 4):

I found out that it is possible to do using LaTeX:

```
---
title: "My raport"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{caption}
---

\def\figurename{MyFigureName}
```

Still: is there any simpler way?

Comment: If the Rmd file might end up as part of a longer document, it may be preferable to use `\renewcommand{\figurename}{MyFigureName}`

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r figWithCaption, echo=F, fig.cap="My Figure Caption"}
plot(cars) # your figure
```
````

Comment: Thank you, but it still generates caption: "Figure 1: My Figure Caption". I want it to be "MyFigureName 1: My figure caption".

Comment: Ah sorry, I haven't read your question thoroughly enough. Does it need to be a specific figure name, or is it about language? If the latter is the case, you can include: `header-includes:  - \usepackage[english]{babel} ` in the YAML header, and instead of "english" type your desired language. Else I don't know an answer to your question..