# Rmarkdown figure caption not printing correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I'm currently using Rstudio and running this code:

```
{r top_3pt_scorers, echo = FALSE}

top_3pt_shooters <- NBAdf %>%
  filter(PTS_TYPE == 3) %>%
  group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Threes_attempted = n(), Threes_made = sum(as.numeric(FGM)),
            Three_point_total = sum(PTS, na.rm = TRUE))

knitr::kable(head(top_3pt_shooters[order(top_3pt_shooters$Threes_made, decreasing = TRUE), ]),
             caption = "The top 3 point scorers in the NBA")
```

But I'm getting this output:

[image]

Whereas my ideal output is:

[image]

Do I need to change something within the kable argument?

Solution:

To solve this issue, I just had to change the following code:

```
{r top_3pt_scorers, echo = FALSE}
```

to

```
{r top3ptscorers, echo = FALSE}
```

Comment: Which figure caption are you looking for? It's printing the name of your code chunk. Maybe it's something else in your `.Rmd` file (e.g. YAML header)?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31336997/13249862)?

Comment: Thank you for the link but I the table caption rather than a figure, e.g. 'Table 1: The top 3 point scorers in the NBA' and then the table below it

Comment: It's worked properly on two other tables but the rest of them aren't working

Comment: You need to provide more details in this case.

Comment: I've just added screenshots to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a code chunk problem. Try this:

````
```{r top_3pt_scorers, echo = FALSE}

top_3pt_shooters <- NBAdf %>%
  filter(PTS_TYPE == 3) %>%
  group_by(PLAYER_NAME) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Threes_attempted = n(), Threes_made = sum(as.numeric(FGM)),
            Three_point_total = sum(PTS, na.rm = TRUE))

knitr::kable(head(top_3pt_shooters[order(top_3pt_shooters$Threes_made, decreasing = TRUE), ]),
             caption = "The top 3 point scorers in the NBA")
```
````

---

You may use `fig_caption = TRUE` in your YAML header.

This may help you:

````
---
title: "Caption"
author: "bttomio"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

## Caption with kable

```{r dt}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, caption = "Demo table", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

```{r dt2}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, caption = "Same demo table", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped", "hold_position"))
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: I've just attempted your solutions but they haven't been successful for me, it's just outputting the same issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? It's hard to know what's going on without knowing the other parts of your `.Rmd` file. Thanks

Comment: I've just added everything I'm using in the post.

Comment: I've found the solution! so it didn't like ```{r top_3pt_scorers}```, I had to change it to ```{r top3ptscorers}``` it didn't seem to like underscores

Comment: I see, good to hear! You can edit my answer or post a new one explaining your solution.