# Change in Rmarkdown table the word Table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

Well I have a table in Rmarkdown but since I write the document in Greek I want also the Table word to be printed in Greek

````
```{r name, echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
   kablegr %>%
     kbl(caption = "**_Πίνακας_**") %>%
       kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")%>%
        column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, border_right = TRUE, color = "black", background = "lightgrey")

 ```
````

what I want is instead o Table to print Πίνακας in each table of my document

```
 Table: --> Πίνακας:
```

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1**

This a solution that keeps the numbering automatically (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52140199/13249862). Nonetheless, I had to suppress the bold face.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "bttomio"
date: "5/10/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=F}
library(captioner)
tables <- captioner(prefix = "Πίνακας")
```

```{r tab1, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  kbl(caption=tables("tab1", "Table Caption")) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")%>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, border_right = TRUE, color = "black", background = "lightgrey")
```

```{r tab2, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  kbl(caption=tables("tab2", "Table Caption")) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")%>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, border_right = TRUE, color = "black", background = "lightgrey")
```
````

-output
[image]

**OPTION 2**

You could try this (`fig_caption: no` in your YAML header):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "bttomio"
date: "5/10/2021"
output: 
  html_document:
    fig_caption: no
---

```{r name, echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  kbl(caption = "**_Πίνακας_**") %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria")%>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, border_right = TRUE, color = "black", background = "lightgrey")
```
````

-output
[image]

Comment: that would be a nice idea but I need to replace Τable with Πίνακας  keeping the numeration

Comment: Not sure you could do that programmatically. You could manually insert the numbering.

Comment: If you are looking for a pdf output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31292674/13249862

Comment: is for html output

Comment: Just updated the answer. If it helped you, please confirm the answer and/or upvote it. Thanks